# 2 applications on phone?

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile-application

I am trying to resolve this issue that I have when I place a splash page on my android app in andriod studio and try to test on my phone 2 icons appear but when I remove the splash java and xml it revert to 1 icon . I'm still new to andriod studio and programming but what am I currently adding that makes that happen?

Comment: please provide your manifest code

Answer (score 1):

This means that you didnt specify the splash screen as the only launcher. As a consequence, Android think that your two activities can be launched separately and create one icon for each.

Check your `AndroidManifest.xml`

you will find your two

```
        <activity
...
        </activity>
```

For your splash screen, add the following:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

For your second activity, the one launched from the splash screen, just use it:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
```

This way you set only your splash screen as a launcher. It will remove the second icon.